# MasterDetailPage on Windows Local Machine - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

I am new to Xamarin Forms. I was trying to implement MasterDetailPage.

In xaml file,

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Text="Sports" />
            <Button Text="Science" />
            <Button Text="Education" />
            <Button Text="Economy" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <local:MainPage></local:MainPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

It looks fine in Android phone.

[image]
[image]

But doesn't looks the same in windows local machine

[image]

**Edited:**

View on android tablet

[image]

Comment: it's not supposed to look identical on every platform

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do, you want to have same master-detail as on Android or? Can you describe your problem more, thanks!

Comment: I want to show navigation on android tablet as well as on windows local machine. It is visible on android phone, but my main motive is to display it on android tablet and windows local machine.

Comment: @AlmirVuk, I found the solution, I have to set "MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover" in .cs file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xamarin form bind the `xamarin.forms` code to the platform native structure. Therefore it may look a bit different on different platforms. This is to make it easier for users to recognize themselves with their own familiar systems. The layout will probobly look a bit different on a windows mobile with another screen ratio.

Read more about the master detail page in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

I hope thís information will help you.

Comment: I have added the view on android tablet. It looks same as windows machine. Is there any way to show navigation on tablets? Thankyou

Comment: Thanks @TechLabradoodle, I just had to set "MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover" in .cs file.